Traefik Helm chart values redirectTo type error
I am I trying to set the value for redirectTo in the Traefik helm chart as below:
ports:
web:
 redirectTo:
   name: websecure
websecure:
 tls:
   enabled: true

When install the helm chart I am getting the following error
coalesce.go:286: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for traefik.ports.web.redirectTo (map[])
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s):
traefik:
- ports.web.redirectTo: Invalid type. Expected: object, given: string

What am I missing here ?
The chart version I am using is 32.1.0.

Your values are missing indentation. "web" and "websecure" are children of "ports".
Also redirectTo has no child name, it is called port:
And your indentation is too low in some lines (1 space):
ports:
  web:
    redirectTo:
      port: websecure
  websecure:
    tls:
      enabled: true

